# Gerunds/present participles of two-verb compounds

Tags: gerunds, compounds, present-participles, conjugation

I use *making-believe* instead of *make-believing* if I need to make a gerund/present participle out of "make-believe", but I just saw this line:

> Brenda rode along, make-believing she was a knight riding to the rescue. (source: Lexico)

The relevant NGram confirms my preference:

[image]

When do we conjugate the first or second verb? What rule governs this?

---

#### Edit

I hope to improve this question following this: A downvote and a closevote demanding "*Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.*" Since they appeared at the time it wouldn't be too risky to assume it is the same user. How much more research is this question supposed to have? I seriously would like to know. The down/closevoter should leave a comment, give some pointers, if you really can.

Comment: @Greybeard On the contrary, your Ngram is not what you think it is. Check out Google Ngrams' info page: https://books.google.com/ngrams/info. Your results are for subtractions. That explains why you are getting steep ups and downs.

Comment: OK although it seems a little more complicated than that. Try the search terms "**make believe,making believe,make believing**" and then look at the examples for each. The guidance is that the first element is the active verb and is inflected, the second element is an infinite/gerund as the object/complement of the verb. To make-believe, to make do, to  make amends, etc.

Comment: @Greybeard Make amends is an interesting example, because most dictionaries define amends as a noun which puts this phrase in a different group from make believe.

Comment: The noun and adjective are *make-believe*, and the verb is *make believe* (no hyphen). So conjugate *make*. Evidence from [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made-believe%2C+made+believe%2C+make-believed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20-%20believe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20believe%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmade%20-%20believe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20believe%3B%2Cc0). And don't use a hyphen.

Comment: A downvote and a closevote demanding "_Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic._" Since they appeared at the time it wouldn't be too risky to assume it is the same user. How much more research is this question supposed to have? I seriously would like to know. The down/closevoter should leave a comment, give some pointers, if you really can.

Answer (score 1):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/make-believe) indicates that it's the first simplex verb in this extraordinary compound verb that is conjugated:

> **make believe** [verb]
>
> to pretend or enact a fantasy
>
> - *the children made believe they were doctors*

As this is contrary to the licensing at Lexico, this is obviously a grey area. For what it's worth, I think that 'made believe' sounds far better than 'make-believed', but 'making believe' doesn't sound too hot.

The use of 'make believe' as a verb is far from common, and its conjugation thus uncertain. The availability of open and hyphenated forms adds to the uncertainty.

Comment: I thought as much. Weird Lexico (Oxford) is not following this.

Comment: They do the research; obviously, as the results differ so markedly, one must suspect that the sample sizes are necessarily almost unacceptably small. _Using 'make[-]believe' as a verb is very rare._

Comment: There are very few V+V multi-word-verb compounds (or colligations?) in English. 'Let go' and 'let fly' are two ('Be ready to duck when she lets go') and 'make do' is another ('We had little milk left, but we made do'). These obviously inflect on the first member.